# How can I see the my methods in deployed contract at near Protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to find how can I see the available methods in my deployed contract at near protocol as I can see them at etherscan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this by code, you can either use the [near-contract-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/near-contract-parser) library, or try to parse the .wasm file deployed on the contract manually.

First, we need to fetch the contract binary (the .wasm file as base64) using a HTTP request. Then the library will get the abstract syntax tree from the .wasm file, parse it, and filter all the exported method names.

[Here is a useful video](https://www.loom.com/share/fb4dc86376774857b34d3f5005c474a3) for learning how the code owner of `near-contract-parser` parsed the binary file on the contract to read out the method names that exist on it.